# Get difference between two DateTimes as a DateTime object?

Tags: java, jodatime

I want to get the difference between two DateTime objects as a DateTime and not as a Period or something like that. How can I do that ?

Comment: So if the date/times are two months apart do you expect the result to be `01 March 1970` ? Can you give an example?

Comment: Why would you do that ? If I calculate the difference between 1pm and 2pm, what would I expect that 1 hour to be in terms of an absolute date/time ?

Comment: How would that be meaningful? I couldn't imagine any context where the difference between "March 3rd 2011" and "January 1st 2008" would be "February 2nd 0003" (or something *like* that with leap years and all those shenanigans).

Comment: I need to make a method that calculates the difference between two dates. Another method uses this difference and accepts a DateTime.

Comment: You need to rewrite that second method, because it doesn't make sense.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't, because it doesn't make sense.

What's the difference between September 25th 2012 and December 25th 2012? It's two months, or ~60 days (I haven't checked exactly) - but it certainly isn't "February 20th 1970" or anything like that.

If you find yourself *wanting* the difference as a `DateTime`, it means something in your design is messed up, and you should revisit it. If you have trouble working out exactly where the problem is, you can give us more information and we may be able to identify where the types are wrong, but fundamentally what you're asking for *won't* work.

Comment: See the constructor - (int year, int monthOfYear, int dayOfMonth, int hourOfDay, int minuteOfHour, int secondOfMinute, int millisOfSecond) 


September 25th 2012 and December 25th 2012 - I want this to be expressed as DateTime(2012,60.....etc). Is this ok ?

Comment: and it does not work, i keep on getting errors like month should be between 1-12 when i use same dates, but that can be worked out.

Comment: A `DateTime` represents a date, and a time.  It does not, and cannot, represent something like "60 days."  You shouldn't be trying to shoehorn this into a `DateTime` -- you should be changing your code so you don't _need_ to shoehorn this into a `DateTime`.

Comment: @davidblaine: In what *possible* way would that make sense? What does a month-of-year of "60" give you a sensible value?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question, you can use the calendar class method [compareTo](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html#compareTo%28java.util.Calendar%29) for an int value representing the number of milliseconds between the two times.

**public int compareTo(Calendar anotherCalendar)**
Compares the time values (millisecond offsets from the Epoch) represented by two Calendar objects.

**Specified by**: compareTo in interface Comparable

**Parameters**: anotherCalendar - the Calendar to be compared.

**Returns**:
A value of 0 if the time represented by the argument is equal to the time represented by this Calendar;
A value less than 0 if the time of this Calendar is before the time represented by the argument;
A value greater than 0 if the time of this Calendar is after the time represented by the argument.

**Throws**:
        NullPointerException - if the specified Calendar is null. 
        IllegalArgumentException - if the time value of the specified Calendar object can't be obtained due to any invalid calendar values.

Answer (score 0):

You always can work with DateFormat and Calendar. It will be easy to calculate the difference between two dates.

See [`DateFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/DateFormat.html), [`SimpleDateFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html) and [`Calendar`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html).

Answer (score 0):

As others have said not sure why you would want this but the following code will give you the number of days between a two dates and if you want it this number plus 1970 date

```
@Test
public void test() {
    DateTime d1 = new DateTime(2011, 1, 1, 0, 0);
    DateTime d2 = new DateTime(2011, 2, 1, 0, 0);
    int days = Days.daysBetween(d1, d2).getDays();
    assertEquals(31, days);

    DateTime dateTime = new DateTime(new Date(0), DateTimeZone.UTC).plusDays(days);
    assertEquals(new DateTime(1970, 2, 1, 0, 0, 0, DateTimeZone.UTC), dateTime);
}
```